# What guage of wire for 10.5 amps at 240V

Tags: electrical

I have a washing machine that requires 240 volts at 10amps. It uses 60 hertz and has a max wattage of 2,300. Am I ok to use 14-3 on a double pole breaker (dedicated circuit) to power this or is a different gauge required?

This is in Ontario Canada

Comment: What country is this in?

Comment: Canada, from OP's other posts. It wouldn't be anywhere East of the Atlantic, as a) we don't use 60Hz & b) 10A 230v would just plug in to any existing socket over here…. & c) we buy our wire by the Amp rating, not in 'guages' really.

Comment: Manufacturer/model #?

Comment: Is this a commercial or industrial washing machine? Alternatively is this a UK or EU machine which will accept 50 hz to 60 hz?

Comment: Came here from HNQ - gauge is spelled wrong in the title. I can’t submit such a small edit.

Comment: Once again, **what is the manufacturer/model number of this machine?** That is key to figuring this out and not just guessing.

Comment: It's a Bosch. I don't have the model atm. I provided all the details I have from the manual.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR Bosch = NEMA 6-15 = 14/2 or 12/2**

A bit unusual, in my experience, to see a washing machine that uses 240V (instead of 120V).

Updated because OP stated this is a Bosch. I don't know which model, but I found a bunch on the official Bosch site. Using [this model as an example](https://www.bosch-home.com/us/productslist/washers-and-dryers/compact-washers/compact-washers/WAW285H2UC#/Tabs=tab-3324792/Togglebox=-1273919852/Togglebox=-172343114/Togglebox=-582378998/Togglebox=-688606933/Togglebox=-960854172/Togglebox=-961685323/Togglebox=1054562090/Togglebox=1883245062/Togglebox=376164562/Togglebox=688446352/). The [spec sheet](https://media3.bosch-home.com/Documents/16168087_WAW285H2UC_Spec_Sheet.pdf) has the key details:

> Power Cord (included)Type [240V; NEMA 6-15, 3-prong]

This particular model uses 2,520 Watts, so slightly more than OP's model, but that's close enough for this question. My hunch is that they use 240V either for more compatibility (common design and parts) with the European market (though this is *not* a "made for Europe" machine - it is 60 Hz and UL listed), or to get a bit more power. There is an option, included with the matching dryer, to power washer and dryer from a standard NEMA 14-30, but they can be powered separately using a pair of NEMA 6-15 or NEMA 6-20.

Now we know this is a *proper* 3-prong plug, not a 3-that-should-be-4. We also know it does *not* need neutral, and that it is fine on a 15A circuit. It is also valid, by default, on a 20A circuit with a NEMA 6-20.

- Breaker: Double 15A or double 20A, with GFCI.
- Cable: 14/2 (15A) or 12/2 (15A or 20A).

Could you use /3 cable? Yes. If you do that, then you could wire this up as an MWBC and connect *both* 120V and 240V receptacles, and then you would be able to plug in either type of washing machine.

Assuming you just wire up a NEMA 6-15 or 6-20 and you use 2-wire cable, you should mark the white wire, which under most circumstances is *only* for neutral, with colored tape (typically black or red, but anything except green or white is fine).

The circuit should be GFCI protected, which in this case means a GFCI breaker, as GFCI receptacles are normally (always? not sure) 120V only.

Comment: It's not hardwired. Sorry for the lack of clarity on that.

Comment: OK. What kind of plug does it come with?

Comment: I don't have that handy. It's 3 prong, I can say that much off the top of my head.

Comment: If it is a *modern* 3-prong then for 240V it should be hot/hot/**ground**, in which case no neutral and use a NEMA 6-15 receptacle and 14/2 instead of 14/3.

Comment: If it's 14-2 then I'd have to use the neutral as a hot and I thought that's forbidden by both NEC and CEC for some time now. I thought all boxes always require a neutral by code

Comment: All *switch* boxes for 120V lighting require neutral by (recent) code. That is so you can add smart switches/timers/etc. later without a problem. But for a pure 240V receptacle you don't need neutral. The other confusion is because "white = neutral" and 14/2 is black/white. But this is one of those exceptions where white *in a cable, not by itself* can be used as a hot conductor.

Comment: @AfterWorkGuinness what is required is to re-mark the white wire a hot color with tape or paint.   *Given how rarely I see this actually done, it's clear some major religion forbids this practice.  In that case, yes,  14/3.*

Comment: If you are running new cable from your panel to the machine location you should consider running 12/3 as the cost is about the same and will allow you to install other machines in future that have greater power requirements.  If the current machine demands a 15A breaker you can install one with the 12ga cable.   If you are breaking walls for a  laundry room reno you should run one 10/3 and two 12/3s, even if unused, to allow flexibility in choosing new machines in future.   I'm not making this an answer because you didn't ask what you "should" do.  14/2 may be all you NEED for this machine.

Comment: 10/3 allows for a standard dryer circuit and the extra 12/3 for additional lights and receptacles. Unknown what else OP has - could be a fully functional room and just needs to add this 240v circuit or could be anything.

Comment: I have additional 20amp receptacles in the room (combined kitchen laundry). I'm all for future-proofing. I'll go with 12/3 for the washing machine.

Comment: Reason we suggest 10/3 is that will support the standard North American electric dryer.  Other than that Code requires only one 120V/20A circuit.

Comment: We had a machine once that had a heater below the basket  that machine could have been 2300 watts.

Comment: Come to think of it, the receptacle for the washer will have to be on a combo arc fault breaker so that rules out using 14-2 (or 12-2) and using the neutral as a hot to get 240 volts. So I'll go with 12-3.

Comment: Again, you are **NOT** "using neutral as a hot". You **may** use **WHITE** as a hot, when a 2-wire cable is appropriate. That is not the same as "using neutral as hot". Whether you need to have a neutral wire connected is an entirely separate question.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I'll correct my terminology. As I understand it, a combo arc fault breaker requires a neutral.  Given that, I don't believe I can use the white wire in 12-2 as a hot in this situation and I'd need to use 12-3 (assuming I opt to go with 20amp over 15amp). Is that right?

Answer (score 3):

Wire gauge will be determined by the amperage rating of the circuit breaker in the power distribution panel. If you have a 15A breaker then 14AWG wire can be used. For a 20A breaker a 12AWG wire would be used. Generally all wiring in a circuit should be the same gauge and must match with the breaker rating.

The amperage load rating of your appliance must be less than the rating of the circuit breaker.

Comment: Given a 2-pole 15amp breaker can put out 3,600 watts and I need only 2,300, I take it I'm good to use a 2-pole 15 breaker then? And given I'd be using a 2-pole 15 am breaker, 14-3 is what I'd use?

Answer (score 2):

If subject to a provision similar to the NEC I would consider that 210.11(C)(2) requires at least one dedicated 20A circuit in a laundry area. If you have a separate 120v existing 20A circuit a new additional receptacle may be able to slide past this requirement, but I would seriously consider #12 awg and a 20A breaker.

Also does the washer installation instructions address this?

Comment: This, because I don't run 14 gauge. Questions only come into play if it should be #10 or larger.

Answer (score 1):

Since we now know you have a Bosch washer, there's no need to rewire anything.  The washer simply **[plugs into the dryer](https://blog.bestbuy.ca/appliances/major-appliances/bosch-laundry-machines-240v-plug-fits-any-home)**.

> When you bring home a Bosch washing machine, you’ll immediately notice that you can’t plug the washing machine straight into your washing machine outlet. That’s because the slightly oversized three prong outlet doesn’t match up.
>
> There’s no need to call in an electrician to rewire your laundry room because the Bosch washing machine plugs straight into the Bosch dryer, and the dryer plugs into the standard 240V dryer outlet.

The washer does have a NEMA 6-15 plug and you certainly can have a new circuit installed just to support this washer if you don't also have the dryer, but the intention from Bosch is that you buy the dryer and washer as a set and use the dryer's power connection to the standard 14-30 dryer plug.

No other washer manufacturer makes washers like this, though, so you're investing a lot into a circuit that you won't need or be able to use when you eventually have to replace this washer.  Every other washing machine plugs into the standard outlet that electrical code requires your laundry room to have to support a normal washing machine.

Bosch is both cutting costs with this manoeuvre, allowing them to harmonize a 240V standard for all their international products, but is also profiting from the brand locking by gambling that most people will rather stick with the brand than pony up for an additional 30% of the purchase price to hire an electrician to add a new circuit *just for this special washer*.

There is also no indication that any other washer manufacturer is going in this direction, so I wouldn't hold out hope that the NEMA 6-15 outlet is going to become a household standard any time soon, or that you will even be able to buy a washer that uses it in the future since Bosch themselves might one day decide that this is a silly strategy and go back to making normal washers with 120V plugs.

Indeed, the overall trend in North America, which has been ongoing for years, is for laundry rooms to require 20A/120V receptacles in new or renovated spaces so there's every indication that, should washing machine manufacturers move towards higher power units, that it is **that** outlet standard they will most likely embrace.

Unless you're obsessed with this specific washer for any particular reason, the most sensible thing to do if you don't intend to buy the dryer would be to simply return it and buy a normal washer with a standard plug instead.

Comment: That works if you have a Bosch dryer. But if your washing machine broke and you got a replacement and picked a Bosch, but your dryer is just fine and you don't plan on replacing it for a while, it is likely a *lot* cheaper to wire up a NEMA 6-15 than to replace the dryer. According to the web site, they start at $1,099.

Comment: I disagree. Nothing wrong with stepping up to new technology a piece at a time. A bit different, but I redid most of kitchen but waited on the refrigerator/freezer and the oven until each died. For the refrigerator/freezer, I planned ahead with a kitchen design that allowed for a bigger model (I know too many people who boxed themselves into a corner and can never get a bigger model without tearing out cabinets) and for the oven ended up doing a bunch of work (demolition and electrical) in order to put in something better. A 6-20 is really *not a big deal*.

Comment: I'm not at all surprised with Best Buy (I'll drive 20 minutes each way extra to go to Micro Center instead of Best Buy) but their blog says **they have European plugs.** That is absolutely, categorically, 100% **wrong**. They are US NEMA 6-15 plugs. They are on the relatively unusual side of things, but they are most definitely US/Canda standard and absolutely not European.

Comment: Except that I'd bet that 99% of the "normal" washers have a NEMA 5-15 plug, because they don't want to count on people having a NEMA 5-20 receptacle, even if it is a 20A circuit. Which means a limit of ~ 1,800 Watts, less if derated for continuous use (that would apply for a dryer, might not for a washer). Looking at a few GE & Whirlpool - they are 120V x 10 to 11 A, so total in the 1,300 Watt range - not nearly as much power. Whether the Bosch's extra power is used well or not, I don't know.

Comment: Lots of people still have 3-wire NEMA 10-30 even though NEMA 14 has been code for a long time. More importantly, the 20A circuit often has 15A receptacles (legally) so from a practical standpoint, almost no manufacturer is going to sell 120V washing machines that need more than 15A because they would have to put on a 5-20 plug and lots of people wouldn't know what to do and would return it and get something else. In this case OP *knows* they need something different and are willing to get a new circuit properly installed.

Comment: Regarding the latest edit, my understanding (an NEC expert can confirm or deny) is that a 20A **circuit** is required but not a 20A **receptacle**. Which would mean, as is often the case in kitchens as well (which require 2 x 20A circuits) that the largest receptacles will in most cases still be 120V @ 15A. Which means that if a manufacturer wants to build washing machines that require more than 1,800 W (or based on 80% derate, 1,440 W) then they require a different receptacle - whether 6-15, 6-20, 5-20 or (as Bosch allows) piggybacking off the dryer 14-30.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact For NEC it's in 210.21(B), and yes, you can put a 20A rated duplex 5-15 outlet on a 20A circuit and have it satisfy code.  But 5-15 outlets cost exactly the same price as 5-20 outlets so, at least in my experience, you'll usually find 5-20 outlets in kitchens and laundry areas that are supplied by 20A circuits. Even if not, really, if you've got the 20A circuit already installed it's a $5 and 5 minute job to change the outlet - a far different proposition from running an entirely new circuit.

Comment: I agree that $5 and 5 minute is a lot better than running a new circuit (which could be $25 to several hundred depending on many factors). But I still contend that since most homes have 5-15 everywhere, most manufacturers will not go the 5-20 route. They'll either keep it compatible with 5-15 or bump up to get a *lot* more power (Bosch).

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I still think it's a hustle.  There's really no benefit to adding more power to a washer - all it can really go into is heating water and the motor just doesn't need that much power.  It's not like the Bosch washer is turning out a load of laundry in half the time of a regular washer - the cycle times are the same as every other washing machine, so I still fail to see the point.  What is all that investment getting you?